# Darkmode feature save toggle state using localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried using localstorage to save the toggle state default mode vs. darkmode but no success so far.

This is my darkmode script in **javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var button = $('.night-mode-button');
  var box = $('.box');
  var lastmodified = $('.lastmodified');
  var pretitle = $('.pre-title');
  var description = $('#description');
  var readmore = $('.readmore');
  var logo = $('.header-logo');
  var h3 = $('h3');
  var body = $('body');
  var h1 = $('h1');
  var nav = $('.nav');
  var dropdown = $('.dropdown');
  var themecheck = $('.theme__check');

  button.click(function() {
    box.toggleClass('darkmode');
    lastmodified.toggleClass('darkmode');
    pretitle.toggleClass('darkmode');
    description.toggleClass('darkmode');
    readmore.toggleClass('darkmode');
    logo.toggleClass('darkmode');
    h3.toggleClass('darkmode');
    body.toggleClass('darkmode');
    h1.toggleClass('darkmode');
    nav.toggleClass('darkmode');
    dropdown.toggleClass('darkmode');
    themecheck.toggleClass('darkmode');
  });
});
```

Comment: You should refactor your CSS so the styling can be applied like `.darkmode .box { ... }` rather than `.box.darkmode { ... }`, that way you only have to `toggleClass` on `html` rather than all your elements.

Comment: Show us your attempt to use local storage.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Can you please show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Mattx I just did...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Hey I think I understood and made an attempt of your suggestion, though it's not working, I probably made a mistake somewhere in the code (sorry for being a noob).

`$(document).ready(function(){
  var button = $('.night-mode-button');
  var darkmode = $('');
  
  
  button.click(function() {
 darkmode.toggleClass('.darkmode'); 
  });
});`

Comment: what do you expect `$('')` to be...? Based on my suggestion, you probably meant to select `$('html')`